# Different Varnish VCL based on URL

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have Magento installation in a subfolder and a WordPress site. How can I use the same Varnish installation for two different CMS?

I have prepared the following default.vcl file code example, but not sure if I am moving in the right direction. Thanks

```
vcl 4.0;
if (req.url ~ "^/path/to/magento/") {
include "magento.vcl";
 } elseif (req.url ~ "^/path/to/wordpress/") {
include "wordpress.vcl";
}
```

P.S. My Varnish version is 4.0

Answer (score 1):

> Before I continue, please be ware of the fact that Varnish 4 is end-of-life. Any bug or error you encounter will not be fixed and can result in unexpected behavior. The best way forward is by upgrading to Varnish 6.

That being said, you are definitely moving in the right direction. But please make sure the included logic is put inside a subroutine.

Your example code will typically live inside `sub vcl_recv {}`. If you have logic that belongs in other subroutines (like `sub vcl_backend_response {}` for example), please make sure you include that logic as well.

Comment: Thank you @Thijs Feryn!